# Android: How to add and stack multiple textviews dynamically on the screen

Tags: android, textview

In my app, user can add a tag in EditText. After hitting "Enter", the tag will be added to the screen. Each tag can have different lengths. User can add as many as he wants. What I want is: one TextView is added after another. When they fill one line, it will start a new row, then another row. Like below (two rows of TextViews):

```
"text 1","text 2","text 3","Another text"
"one","Monday"
```

Do I have to get the widths of the screen and every TextView and then do some calculations? Or is there a graceful way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` as a container and you should add `TextView`s as programmatically. While adding TextViews, you need to calculate screen width and each TextViews width. If last added TextView width exceeds the limit, you need to move that to next row.

You can get Screen Width like below:

```
public static int getScreenWidth(Context ctx) {
    int width = 0;
    try {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return width;
}
```

But, there are many libraries to achieve that. You do not have to make this from scratch.

https://github.com/Cutta/TagView

https://github.com/kaedea/android-tagview

https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView

https://github.com/mcharmas/android-tagview

Comment: Those libraries seem to all have their own issues. I'll probably add `TextView` programmatically. Thanks for confirming I have to get widths of the TextViews and the screen. Wish we had a layout that could do what I want here.